# lineTo not working properly

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

i'm having problems with my code or something... the thing is i'm using lineTo from one objects coordinates to the other's, but no mater where the second object is the line always goes off to a random direction somewhere in the lower left corner and i'm stuck.

here is the code:

```
        var spr:Shape = new Shape();
        spr.graphics.clear();
        spr.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xffffff);
        spr.x = latM[1].x;
        spr.y = latM[1].y;
        spr.graphics.lineTo(latM[0].x,latM[0].y);
        trace("latM[0].x = "+latM[0].x+"\tlatM[0].y = "+latM[0].y+
              "\nlatM[1].x = "+latM[1].x+"\tlatM[1].y = "+latM[1].y);
        spr.graphics.lineTo(latM[0].x,latM[0].y);
        addChild(spr);
```

after a few tries i found out that all lines point [wrote lean by mistake] towards the lower left TT_TT..

Comment: what do you mean lean towards the lower left?

Comment: i'll give an example it's simpler that way: let's say i start at x 100 and y 100 and i want the line to co to x 200 y 50 it will point downword thowrd the lower left corner, if i point from the same spot to lets say x 20 y 500 i'll get the same result

Comment: By changing the Y you are making the line "point down". Am I missing something or is this not the desired effect you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean lean towards the lower left?
You can only draw a straight line with lineTo.
"lineTo" only goes from the current point to the point set via its parameters.
The moveTo function will move the point without drawing.
The following code will draw a box 100 X 100

```
var spr:Shape = new Shape();
spr.graphics.clear();
spr.graphics.lineStyle(2,0xff00ff);
spr.graphics.moveTo(0,0);
spr.graphics.lineTo(0,100);
spr.graphics.lineTo(100,100);
spr.graphics.lineTo(100,0);
spr.graphics.lineTo(0,0);
addChild(spr);
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume latM[1] and latM[0] are the two shapes your trying to draw a line between. If that is case did you notice you have two lineTo going to the same point?

What you need is.

```
spr.graphics.moveTo(latM[0].x, latM[0].y);
spr.graphics.lineTo(latM[1].x, latM[1].y);
```

Here is a small prototype to show you how it works. (This is not meant to be super solid code it is a quick and dirty prototype.)

```
package src 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var obj1:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var obj2:Sprite = new Sprite();
        private var lineSprite:Sprite = new Sprite();

        // for testing your line.
        // we don't really need it for this prototype however it
        // is being used since this is how your accessing your Objects.
        private var latM:Array = [];

        public function Main() 
        {
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);
        }

        private function initMain(e:Event):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initMain);

            obj1.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            obj1.graphics.beginFill(0xccccff);
            obj1.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            obj1.graphics.endFill();
            obj1.x = 100;
            obj1.y = 100;

            obj2.graphics.lineStyle(1, 0);
            obj2.graphics.beginFill(0xffcccc);
            obj2.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 20);
            obj2.graphics.endFill();
            obj2.x = 400;
            obj2.y = 200;

            // for testing your line.
            latM.push(obj1, obj2);

            addChild(obj1);
            addChild(obj2);
            addChild(lineSprite);

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, handleEnterFrame);
        }

        private function handleEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
        {
            // this will clear and redraw the line between the two sprites
            // every frame and thus always be up to date.
            lineSprite.graphics.clear();
            lineSprite.graphics.lineStyle(2, 0xff0000);
            lineSprite.graphics.moveTo(latM[0].x, latM[0].y);
            lineSprite.graphics.lineTo(latM[1].x, latM[1].y);

            //obj1.x++; // uncomment this line and you can watch it move and keep the line perfect.
        }

    }

}
```